# Cannot update Azure AD password with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The following is the request I'm using for the `PATCH` request for updating a user's password.

```
var token = TokenHelper.GetToken().AccessToken;
var client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + person.UserPrincipalName);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\"passwordProfile\": {\n \"password\": \"" + person.NewPassword + "\"\n}\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

If I type a complex password I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "One or more properties contains invalid values.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5d97b465-7b27-4328-b0d9-4e9112f2257e",
      "date": "2020-01-03T16:57:35"
    }
  }
}
```

If I type a simple password I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "The specified password does not comply with password complexity requirements. Please provide a different password.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "986fd0da-90d4-45c7-ba74-1ba2bec61956",
      "date": "2020-01-03T17:05:15"
    }
  }
}
```

If I type no password my response is a `204 No Content (success)` and it is working fine if I update other fields(i.e. `mobileNumber`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change a user's password, you need to authenticate using either the Authorization Code or Implicit OAuth grant. In addition, you need to request the delegated scope `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following permission is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

You should also set `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` to `true`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've included this: 
My app has delegated access to:
`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`
`User.Read`
`User.ReadWrite`

and application access to
`User.ReadWrite.All`

The TokenHelper creates the OAuth2 code through
`var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/company/oauth2/v2.0/token");`

Comment: That looks like Client Credentials, not Authorization Code. A token cannot have _both_ Application and Delegated scopes. It is one or the other based on which OAuth grant you used.